# Get struct file from of a given struct socket in kernel space

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I need to get the struct file that is associated with a specific struct socket. I saw in the kernel source, in the socket.c file, that there the function struct socket *sockfd_lookup(int fd, int *err), which given a fd returns the socket that this fd belongs to. Is there any way to do the opposite thing? i mean to take the fd of the struct socket. I need to do this in a loadable kernel module.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket struct has a member that is pointer back to its file struct. See linux/net.h struct socket definition

Answer (score 2):

Does the `file` member of `struct socket` not hold what you're looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately it is NULL. I get the struct socket from the kernel call  int security_socket_post_create(struct socket *sock, int family, int type, int protocol, int kern). It is called before the int sock_create(int family, int type, int protocol, struct socket **res) call exits.

Comment: I see.  Unfortunately your question is not well posed -- the security_socket_post_create() hook is called in sock_create(), before sock_map_fd()/sock_alloc_file() call assigns a file.  So in that security hook, there is no file associated with the socket yet.